# copy webpack plugin error options has an unknown property 'to'

Tags: webpack, copy-webpack-plugin

I am having issues with the `Copy Webpack` plugin. I have checked the documentation (https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/) and seems like I am using the correct config, still I am getting the error:

`ValidationError: Invalid options object. Copy Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema. - options[0] has an unknown property 'to'.`

Here is the config I am using as per link shared above. **The from and to has been updated with my environment details.**

```
import CopyPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin';

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "source", to: "dest" },
        { from: "other", to: "public" },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```

I am using `copy-webpack-plugin` package version `^11.0.0` and `webpack` package version `^5.74.0`

Anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All was done correct as per original post. The Babel config was missing.
**To fix this** also check your Babel config and be sure the same is being done there.

Comment: want to put that babel config here?